Using Azure Devops API in Python to fetch PR modified files and get the diff
I have this function of getting modified files in Azure Devops PR:
def fetch_pr_diff(pr_id):
    try:
        # Establish connection and get the Git client
        connection = get_azure_devops_connection()
        git_client = connection.clients.get_git_client()
        
        # Retrieve pull request iterations
        iterations = git_client.get_pull_request_iterations(
            repository_id=repository_id,
            project=project_name,
            pull_request_id=pr_id
        )
        
        # Get the latest iteration
        latest_iteration = max(iterations, key=lambda x: x.id)
        
        # Fetch changes for the latest iteration
        iteration_changes = git_client.get_pull_request_iteration_changes(
            repository_id=repository_id,
            project=project_name,
            pull_request_id=pr_id,
            iteration_id=latest_iteration.id
        )
        
        # Initialize the diff content
        diff_content = ""
        
        # Loop through the changes to extract diffs for each file
        for change in iteration_changes.change_entries:
            if change.additional_properties['item'] is not None:  # Only process items with valid file information
                change = change.additional_properties['item']
                file_path = change['path']
                
                # Check the change type (e.g., modified, added, deleted)
                change_type = iteration_changes.change_entries[0].additional_properties['changeType']
                
                # Process modified files
                if change_type in ['edit', 'add']:
                    # Fetch the file content of the latest version
                    file_content = git_client.get_item_content(
                        repository_id=repository_id,
                        project=project_name,
                        path=file_path
                    )
                    file_content_ = ''.join(chunk.decode('utf-8') for chunk in file_content)
                    # Add file details to the diff content
                    diff_content += f"File: {file_path}\n"
                    diff_content += f"Change Type: {change_type}\n"
                    diff_content += f"Content:\n{file_content_}\n\n"
                elif change_type == 'delete':
                    # If the file is deleted, just log the deletion
                    diff_content += f"File: {file_path}\n"
                    diff_content += f"Change Type: {change_type}\n"
                    diff_content += "Content: File deleted.\n\n"

        return diff_content

the problem is that i want fetch only the modified part, and not the whole file.
how can i just get the modified part between the commited file and the master?
thanks!

Maybe this is an answer; let me know if it helps and I'll make it one: Conceptually, you can do what you want from the command line quite easily, and you should be able to do the same from python. Suppose your PR ID is 1234. First create a branch that contains the merge commit of PR 1234: git fetch origin refs/pull/1234/merge:test-branch That command will get the current (latest iteration) of the PR's merge commit and create a new branch called test-branch. Now show the diff: git diff test-branch~1 test-branch (This is the diff of all files in the PR. You can filter by file if needed.)

yes I Know but i find it hard to so using the azure devops api
